# date.js not calculating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to check if the selected day is a sunday(jquery ui), if it is then adjust it to the saturday before and calculate day-5, day-4 and day-3. My code just returns the same day for each.

c1, c2 and c3 are the same.

```
if(Date.parse($('#arrival_date').val()).is().sunday()) {
    first_day = Date.parse($('#arrival_date').val()).add(-1).days();    
}
else {
    first_day = Date.parse($('#arrival_date').val());
}

console.log(first_day);

var c1 = first_day.add(-5).days();
var c2 = first_day.add(-4).days();
var c3 = first_day.add(-3).days();
```

Comment: I'm betting that all three of those variables are 12 days before `#arrival_date`. Is this the case? (add another log after the three assignments and post the result)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `.add()` method changes the `first_day` variable. Try

```
var c1 = first_day.clone().add(-5).days();
var c2 = first_day.clone().add(-4).days();
var c3 = first_day.clone().add(-3).days();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @trojandestroy pointed out (while is was writing this answer), you get such results because days you add sum up.

This may be a little bit counterintuitive, but it works like this - by calling `first_day.add(-5).days();` you **change** the value of `first_day`.

I made [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5c6R/) to prove that it actually works that way.

After calling `var c1 = first_day.add(-5).days();` both `c1` and `first_day` point to 5 days  before.

Answer (score 0):

All of your `.add()` statements operate on the same object, and you set `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` equal to the same object. This means you have four variables all equal to the exact same object.

To fix this, combine a constructor with the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object's [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method like so:

```
var c1 = new Date(first_date.getTime()).add(-5).days();
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55qFP/1/) comparing the two methods.